# SpringBoot 1.5 : @SpringBootTest and memory Database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

I have a SpringBoot application with spring data/jpa to connect for database.
 And a propertie file yml where defined the database connection.

Everything works very well.

I create a test like that :

```
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyMicroServiceApp.class, webEnvironment=SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyMicroServiceAppTest {

@Test
public <T> void postConnex() {
    //Create Object connexCreate
    ...

    // Create POST
    ResponseEntity<Udsaconnex> result1 = this.restTemplate().postForEntity("http://localhost:" + port + "/v1/connex",
            connexCreate, Udsaconnex.class);
    id = result1.getBody().getIdconnex();
    assertEquals(result1.getBody().toString().isEmpty(), false);
    }
}
```

For my test, i have not configured properties for database connection but the test work and i view in console that :
Hibernate: drop table connex if exists
I don't understand why, *@SpringBootTest* mock database like *@DataJpaTest* automatically ??
It's possible but i don't find anything about that in spring boot documentation.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `application.yml` file specifying DB location, then `SpringBootTest` will obviously use the same configuration and will use your configured DB.

Comment: I have not a `application.yml`, file specifying DB location.   
I have also shutdown my database.   
I view also in console :   

    Hibernate: create table connex(id bigint generated by default as ... primary key (id))

Answer (score 0):

From the title of your question I guess you have an in-memory database in your build dependencies. Spring-boot has some autoconfiguration for certain database (H2, HSQL, Derby) if they are found on the classpath. See this link for a list of the supported databases:

[Spring Boot Embedded Database Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.13.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-database-support)